# How to prevent included modules from logging in Python

Tags: python, logging

I have a Python script that uses other modules like

```
import gnupg
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def __init__(self):
    logger.setLevel(level=logging.INFO)
    .....
```

But even when the logging level is set explicitly, the debug logs from the gnupg lib shows up.  How do I disable the debug logs in a module that I don't own?

Answer (score 1):

Calling

```
logging.getLogger('gnupg').setLevel(60)
```

should remove all log messages from gnupg. You can set configure the level to allow some important messages in the log.

If you are unsure of the name of a logger you can inspect all registered loggers like this

```
print(list(logging.Logger.manager.loggerDict.keys()))
```